# Fast generation of Excel reports using C#

Tags: open-source, c#, .net, microsoft-excel

We would like to use Open XML in my project to generate Excel reports (`.xlsx`).

We have requirement where we do styling, copying, inserting ranges with format, inserting page breaks. It is important that report generation should be fast. We want to use an open source product.

I've found ClosedXML and SpreadSheetLite, which one would be best? Is there a better choice?

Comment: I don't understand your question: what input do you generate the reports from? OpenXML? What kind — spreadsheets?

Comment: @Gilles: OpenXML is the offical name for microsofts .xslx (the spreadsheet equiv of .docx), really it is neither open nor xml. It is almost XML though, it is a bunch of xml files is a zip archive.

Answer (score 1):

## [linqtoexcel](http://code.google.com/p/linqtoexcel/)

[NuGet](http://www.nuget.org/packages/LinqToExcel/1.7.1) 
Last time I had to interact with Excel from C# I used linqtoexcel.
It is MIT license, with is very permissible open source.

I found it quite good. 
I definitely did some styling, like cell colour in report generation.
I don't remember about inserting page breaks.
I had no issues with speed.

You are likely already using a lot of LINQ (ie IEnumerable) in your report generation, so it comes across very naturally.
My report generation ended up being a thin GUI around a bunch of LINQ statements.